# GitLab Community Edition. Есть ли ограничение на количество используемых gitlab-runner(ов)?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Собираемся развернуть стенд для тестирования CI цепочки в GitLab, но есть опасения, что не уложимся по GitLab-runner(ам)

На сайте самого Gitlab не нашел нужного мне ответа. Скажите, как посмотреть или хотя бы найти инфу сколько раннеров можно использовать?

Answer (score 1):

На self-hosted gitlab CE или gitlab EE Core лимиты по количеству управляемых собственных раннеров отсутствуют. Сколько поднимете и подключите - столько и будет.

Ваш администратор gitlab сервера может настраивать лимиты на количество параллельных джоб, параллельных пайплайнов, проектов которые могут использовать раннер. А сами раннеры можете поднимать на своём железе сколько угодно и управлять ими как угодно.

Comment: Я бы добавил, что ограничение есть, но оно в железе, а не в софте

Comment: Безусловно вы правы, ограничение может быть по железу, и оно решается на уровне закупок железа, а не доступности фичи. Только тогда это был бы вопрос "сравнение CI в разрезе сколько раннеров можно запускать на одном и том же объёме железа - какую CI выбрать из соображений экономии на железе?"

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.